# How to use google docs or sheets as input document to knowledge connectors

Tags: google-docs, dialogflow-es

I am trying out the features of Knowledge connectors in Dialogflow Enterprise Edition. Where I have tried adding documents from storage-bucket with both CSV and HTML format and it works as expected.

But when I tried accessing documents from Google Docs or from Google Sheets it throws an error saying 'Fail to crawl'. I assume this is due to lack of permission, please let me know is there a way to read it from Docs or sheets directly if so how to do that.

Comment: kindly consider more information in your answer

Comment: I also tried to link, gave permissions as well as published the Google Doc to the web. I also get the same error!

Comment: @Inder - That's my question and more over what additional information is required.

Comment: I would recommend exporting the contents of the doc or spreadsheet to HTML  (File -> Download as... -> Web Page) and storing this in your storage bucket.

Answer (score 1):

Dialogflow currently does not support this. The workaround is to convert the Google Sheets into a CSV and importing into Dialogflow.

https://dialogflow.com/docs/agents/knowledge-connectors